# Looking for a platform to show custom maps

Tags: android, dictionary, android-mapview

I'm looking for a platform for showing custom maps on android mobile phones and tablets.
It seems like Google's MapView is the most common (or the only?) maps platform for the Android, but my problem with it is that I can't use my own custom maps with it.

Is there any 3rd party custom maps platform for the Android? If not, can someone please try to lead me into a way to implement my own solution?

I need all the basic map features such as - Panning, zooming, layers.

I'm still very flexible with methods of how to implement my map data, so every suggestion counts!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenStreetMap supports offline and online maps. OSM API has all the features that Google Maps API has, same (almost) principles apply on OSM as they do on Google Maps.

For the @Spacedman answer, yes you can integrate the HTML that contains the js with OpenLayers in `WebView`

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers (mobile version) plus Javascript? Assuming you are making a mostly standalone app then I'm not sure about how well it all works running off local URLs instead of a web server, but I can't see any problems that can't be solved one way or another.

Can you tightly integrate it into Android apps? I don't know, I assume you need some kind of web page view part and send it to your HTML that uses OpenLayers javascript for the mapping...